# userInfo by clicking on notification when the app are closed

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, notifications, userinfo

I'm doing an app that schedules local notifications and saves an userInfo. That's part its ok.

But when the app is closed, if a Notification appears and the user clicks, the method is not called and I can't handle userInfo.

I saw that there's a new way to receive a notification with `UNUserNotificationCenter`. But is not working too.

I've tried it that way, but I did not succeed:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    if let yourData = userInfo["yourKey"] as? String {
        // Handle your data here, pass it to a view controller etc.
    }
}
```

That's my implementation in AppDelegate:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let lNotification = UILocalNotification()
    lNotification.userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Handle your data here, pass it to a view controller etc.

}
```

Anyone, to help me? I saw all the questions related here and didn't found anything.

Comment: Why you create new instance of UILocalNotification() in didReceive method?
What is applicationWorker? Could you show the code of applicationWorker and its manage() method?

Comment: @AntonNovoselov Thanks for the reply, however, this implementation of the method is not the point. The problem is that when the app launches by notification, this function was not called.

Comment: @AntonNovoselov The point is, how do I call the function when I open the application by clicking the notification. I appreciate your help!

Comment: check my answer - check if you registered for notifications

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered for notifications?
If not, add this to AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
// Register Notifications
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge], completionHandler: { granted, error in

            if granted {
                print("User notifications are allowed")
            } else {
                print("User notifications are NOT allowed")
            }
        })
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```